# Lagrange's interpolation coding fault result

Tags: matlab, interpolation, numerical-methods

I've tried to compute Lagrange interpolation method in MATLAB for `y=x^2+xe^(x)`. I wrote the following code:

```
clc
clear
close all

x0=4.7;
n=10;
x=linspace(0,5,n);
y=x.^2+x.*exp(x);

syms t
L=sym(ones(1,n));
P_x=sym(0);
for i=1:n
    for j=1:n
        L_improcess=(t-x(j))/(x(i)-x(j));
        if(i==j)
            continue
        end
        L(i)=L(i)*L_improcess;
        P_x=y(i)*L(i)+P_x;
    end
end
P=double(subs(P_x,t,x0));
disp(['Lagrange interpolation: P= ',num2str(P)])
disp(['the real value from original function is:' num2str(x0^2+x0*exp(x0))])
```

so the result for `x0=4.7`was:

```
Lagrange interpolation: P= 20195.8626
the real value from original function is:538.8417
```

I'm wondering how the difference between two result(both of the them must be almost same)
the Lagrange interpolation method for `f(x)` is like this:

[image]

more information about Lagrange interpolation is available 
[here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/523907/explanation-of-lagrange-interpolating-polynomial?noredirect=1&lq=1) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
P_x=y(i)*L(i)+P_x;
```

should be in the loop over i, not j.